# How to public link to certain group or users

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using google cloud storage to public html pages that can load data from json files.

If I use the public link, the web page works great, however, the only problem is that it is open to the public. If I open the public link using browser private mode, it can still work, which is not secure.

Is there a way to share public link to only owner of the html file, or to a certain group, instead of to the whole public.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google Cloud Storage as a [static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) does not generally support authenticated access. You can use [cookie-based authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#cookieauth) in coordination with ACLs, but this is not available through custom domains.

Comment: Hi, @Nathan, If I use the storage.cloud.google.com url to allow authentication users to view the file, the html file couldn't fetch the json data which is located in the same folder. if I use the storage.googleapi.com url, then it works, but anonymous user can also read it. How to deal with this situation? @~@

Comment: The former, for security reasons, redirects to a short-lived domain to serve that object's data. At the moment, you cannot use that domain to reach other object data. As such, you have to go out of your way to reference your JSON data cross-domain at the explicit storage.cloud.google.com domain again, as relative paths won't work.

Comment: And trying it myself, I find that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing. Filing an internal issue.

Comment: In this case, no matter which way we gonna use, we have to public either of the html file or the json data then, which in either way, it won't be totally secure.

Comment: An alternative would be to have the JavaScript in the public html doc do two things: (1) make an authenticated request to a web service (yours or Firebase) to get a download URL for the JSON, (2) use XHR to download the JSON through the download URL rather than going through a Cookie-based authentication endpoint. If all the formatting is in the JSON, then you could even make the original web page public since all the interesting pieces are behind access control.

Comment: Let me try with that. Thank you so much for your help.